# Photoshop CS6 visual basic select an image in layer

Tags: vb.net, scripting, photoshop

I would like to know how can i select an image in layer? My problem that, i import an image to my psd file, but the paste command place the center of my canvas the image, and i would like to place the pasted image top left corner.

Please help me somebody!

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new layer
2. Import a picture in to that (new) layer
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to make free transform of the picture and that place it wherever you want

Comment: Thats okay, but i would like to write a script for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by reading 'Adobe Intro To Scripting' in your ExtendScript Toolkit program files directory (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Utilities - CS6\ExtendScript Toolkit CS6\SDK\English)

You can use the following snippet to a copy a layer from one document to another.

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument
var moveTo = app.documents.getByName('Untitled-1')

var newLayer = docRef.activeLayer.duplicate(moveTo, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING)
```

You can then use the 'translate' method on the ArtLayer object to adjust the position as needed.